# How to enable iOS browser to login with facebook from web page (not app)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-login

I have a web site, that uses facebook to login.

I would like iOS user of safari, to be able to login into this site. You understand i'm NOT talking about a native iOS app..... just a web site visit.

Currently, user can't login from iOS safari, as they can from any desktop environement.
Either login link is inactive, or there is an error message instead of the login popup.

So what should I implement on website to have facebook login work on iOS browser ?

Comment: What code are you using for login?  What is the error message?

Comment: This shouldn't be in the Objective-C category if you're only talking about your site working with iOS devices.